# Minified JS find and replace a valid strategy for substitution?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, minify, bundling-and-minification

For reasons not important to the question (using the output of create-react-app, would like to parameterize some variables POST build time i.e as they're deployed), I am in a scenario where I would like to replace all instances of a string i.e "**REPLACE_ME**" with a value.

This would be trivial if I had access to the un-minified javascript; however, I am wondering if a find and replace on the minified javascript will suffice?

Comment: Minified JS should keep all strings instact, so yes, it should just work.

Comment: It depends on the transformations that the code undergoes.  If your transform does something weird like base64 encoding everything before transmitting, a find/replace might not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create-react-app is using Webpack under the hood, You can use [`webpack.DefinePlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) to achieve that in a build time.

```
// webpack.config.js
const webpack = require('webpack');

const config = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    ...
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      REPLACE_ME: JSON.stringify('yourBuildTimeValueGoesHere'),
    }),
    ...
  ],
  ...
}

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: This requires ejecting or using forked `react-scripts`.

Comment: I think this is a viable approach; however,  I am looking to parameterize **after** build time - the deployment pattern actually is taking the output of react-scripts build & deploying the minified js/css & assets to an nginx server, so it is during the deployment of the server that I want to parameterize the variables... Currently wondering if a sed replace in the startup scripts of the server will suffice

Comment: As @chrisG said, strings remain as is in the minified files, so sed should work.